# Assumption of interior solution in the Lagrangian method

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics, optimization, lagrangian

Why do we need to assume an interior solution before using Lagrangian method for utility maximization problems?

Comment: It would be helpful if you would state exactly what the "Lagrangian method" you are using is. There are versions that work not just for interior solutions and even the meaning of an interior solution can be rather subtle.